# Why there is % symbol in the end of my output?

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, fish

Every time I get this symbol at the end of my output. This only happens in VS Code.

[image]

Comment: Should this question have some kind of mac tag I did not get the same result on linux

Comment: @Simson Whether you get it depends on which shell you use, not whether you are using Linux or Mac. E.g. if I type `echo -n "foo"` in a zsh shell on Linux, I get it too.

Comment: maybe a zsh tag or maybe not it is border case.

Comment: that is a shell prompt, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362772/what-is-percent-sign-prompt-in-a-shell (fyi, bash use $ or #, while zsh/fish use %)

Comment: @Kristian That isn't the `%` he is referring to in this question, rather it is the one at the end of the "roshan" line, which has a white background.

Comment: @RoshanSingh: _Every time I get this symbol_ .... Does this also occure if you simply do a `echo foo`?

Comment: This happens on zsh on Mac but not on bash. `%` is the prompt symbol for zsh as mentioned in another comment. You can change your default shell in terminal settings to `/bin/bash` from `/bin/zsh` if needed.

Answer (score 6):

This means that the program exited without printing a newline after the last line of output. You can change it to the following, and it should go away:

```
cout << "roshan\n";
```